# Foreign key in hibernate, why create objects, how to update a record in referenced entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate environment. I have a basic question and I'm still trying to understand why people are picking Hibernate over SQL.

I have two tables, lets say one is user, one is a book.

A user can has many books, but a book only has a one owner.

If I used SQL, I try to write at

```
Table User, 
  int uid
  PRIMARY KEY (uid)

Table Book,
    int bid
    int oid //ownerid
    PRIMARY KEY (bid)
    FOREIGN KEY (oid) REFERENCES User(uid)
```

I couldn't do this in Hibernate. I've tried the following:

Generated a user table without any relation, only `@Id` annotation for uid.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private Long uid;

    public Long getUid()
    { return uid;}
}
```

Generated a book table, but I cannot understand this point. Everything on the internet says that I need to use `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumns`. If I use them I need to have an object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="uid",
       referencedColumnName = "What should I write here?")
    @Column(name ="oid") //owner id
    private User user;
}
```

1- Why would I need to create a user object for my uid in book table? I just want to store a userid in my books table with Foreign Key constraint (If the user does not exist, then the book cannot be exist either)

2- Also, if I want to reach the userid of the owner, should I use this:

```
public Long getOwnerId()
{
 return user.getUid();
}
```

3- If I want to change the owner of the book, what should I do? Since there is a whole user member in my book object, how can I update only the ownerid in my book table?

Answer (score 0):

> Why would I need to create a user object for my uid in book table?

You don't need to change anything to your database table. Hibernate will read the oid from the book table, and will populate the `Book.user` field with the object of type User identified by this oid.

That way, when you display the information about a book in your application for example, and you want the name of the owner to be displayed, all you need to do is

```
display(book.getUser().getName());
```

Instead of having to get the ID of the user, then execute a second database query to get the user.

> if I want to reach the userid of the owner, should I use this:

yes. Or you don't ad any method, because any caller is able to do `book.getUser().getUid()` by itself.

> If I want to change the owner of the book, what should I do?

Assuming you have the uid of the new owner, you would get the user identified by this ID, and set in on the book:

```
User newOwner = entityManager.find(User.class, newOwnerId);
// or User newOwner = entityManager.getReference(User.class, newOwnerId);
// depending on what you prefer
book.setUser(newOwner);
```

Regarding your mapping of the ManyToOne, it's wrong. You need to read the Hibernate manual, and the javadoc, instead of trying random things. It should simply be

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "oid")
private User user;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a ManyToOne Entity you just need to specify the name of yourforeign key inside the @JoinColumn annotation, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book{
   //private Long bid;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="oid")
   private User user;
}
```

The `referencedColumnName` paramether is most used for ManyToMany relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is a object relational mapper to represent the table based data structure of a relational database in a usual object oriented way, nothing more or less.

You dont have to use annotations like @ManyToOne, @OneToMany, etc. You can just do this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private Long uid;

    // setters and getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "bid")
    private Long bid;

    @Column(name = "oid")
    private Long oid;

    // setters and getters
}

EntityManager em;
Long uid = em.createQuery("SELECT u.uid FROM User u WHERE ....", Long.class).getSingleResult();
book.setUid(uid);
```

Most developers dont want to handle with that much withs IDs and database access etc. They just want to access their business model in a natural object oriented way and there hibernate or JPA comes in:

```
EntityManager em;
User user1 = em.find(User.class, 1L);
Book book1 = new Book();
book1.setUser(user1);
```

1. You dont have to create a User instance for every single Book instance. Just reuse the existing User instance.

In your Example i would do the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {
    // ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Book book) {
        book.setUser(this);
        books.add(book);
    }

    public void remove(Book book) {
        book.setUser(null);
        books.remove(book);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {
    // ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="oid", referencedColumnName = "uid")
    private User user;
}

EntityManager em;
User user1 = em.find(User.class, 1L);
Book book1 = new Book();
Book book2 = new Book();
user1.addBook(book1);
user1.addBook(book2);

book1.getUser(); // user1
book2.getUser(); // user1
```

2. Yes, if u want to handle with bare IDs
3. Set another User via setter. The corresponding uid in the book table will be updated.

   book1.setUser(user2);

will result in the statement

```
update BOOK set oid = 2 where bid = 1;
```